# Int range array into an string array in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, int, range

How can i convert an range int array into an string array?

Like this range int array:

```
let data = [Array(1...9), Array(0...59), Array(0...59)]
```

To an string array like:

```
let data = [["1", "2", "3",.....], ["0","1", "2", "3",...], ["0","1", "2", "3",...]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
data.map{ $0.map(String.init) }
```

Comment: Nice solution! Very concise.

Comment: Can you explain what `String.init` mean. Why `String.init()` cannot run?

Comment: `map` function takes `Int->SomeType` as a parameter. So, I pass `String.init`, which is a String initilizer. It's like when you call `String(123)`, you can also call String.init(123). Finally, since `String.init` has many signatures, Swift Compiler automatically infer the type to `Int->String`

Answer (score 0):

```
let data = [Array(1...9), Array(0...59), Array(0...59)]

var stringArray = Array<Array<String>>()

for array in data {
    var subArray = Array<String>()

    for item in array {
        subArray.append(String(item))
    }

    stringArray.append(subArray)
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try like this when you get the value from array.

Code Snippets:

```
let num = [1, 2, 3]
let data = [num, num, num]

let value = data[0]

for x in value {
    print(String(x))
}
```